# which is better ng-table or ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs

I want the table that I show on the client side to be more responsive. Like when I use "ng-table", when viewed on any other device than PC or laptop it seems to be responsive to a limited extent. So should I switch to "ng-grid"?

Comment: but ng-grid , row height dynamic increase  option not included . it may affect you view and responsiveness

Answer (score 8):

**Difference for Better Choice**

- [ng-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid)
- [ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table)

Both are good, but implemented differently. Either you pick will probably be more based on personal preference than anything else.

**[ng-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid)** is based on SlickGrid which is a pretty high performant data grid, ng-grid is purely Angular. It is highly customiz-able and gets the job done.

**[ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table)** because it is a simpler version of ng-grid and uses tables. It is a very nice little library that allows you to get up and running quickly. It is exactly what you need when you have to render a simple table with Angular.

Happy Helping!

Comment: Thanks for the info but I want something more decisive. Like will ng-grid fit more smoothly than ng-table on a mobile device?

Comment: ng-table can be better